# MCP1703 quiescent current is very high

Tags: voltage, voltage-regulator

I want to use the MCP1703 regulator in battery powered projects.  The datasheet of this regulator says that the quiescent current is typical 2 uA.

I measured the quiescent current for the MCP1703-5 at 80 uA.  For the MCP1703-3.3 I measured 50uA of quiescent current.

For measurement I connected the (6 to 12) volt DC to input and left the output unconnected.

Why is the quiescent current so high ?

[image]

Comment: In addition to the need for ceramic caps, I am hesitant to trust that type of bread board. It does not necessarily produce reliable low-impedance connections from one part to another. It would be better to solder into perf board, for example, or buy a SOT223 breakout board and put the input and output caps right on the breakout board. Microchip also sells an evaluation board for SOT23 regulators. If you want to try out the SOT23 version of the part. Search for this: "SOT23-3EV-VREG"

Comment: According to the [datasheet,](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/22049e.pdf) you measure the quiescent current through the GND pin (center pin and tab on your chip) **only.** Any other current you measure is **not** the quiescent current.  Your picture doesn't show how your ammeter is connected.

Comment: If the yellow alligator clip is connected to ground, then it looks like your output capacitor is connected between in and out rather than between out and ground. (But it's hard to tell due to the image focus) It also looks like your input capacitor could be reversed, which will also cause excess leakage currents (if it doesn't cause fireworks)

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you didn't connect an output capacitor when measuring the \$I_q\$.

From the first page of the datasheet, this regulator is "Stable with 1.0 µF to 22 µF Ceramic Output Capacitance". This implies it might not be stable without an output capacitor.

If you connect it in an unstable configuration, it could oscillate, leading to much higher \$I_q\$ than expected or specified.

As pointed out in comments, an input capacitor is also required to match the \$I_q\$ test conditions. Whether this actually has an important effect probably depends what kind of power source you use and how long are the wires connecting it to your device under test.

Comment: +1 In fact it's specifically stated to be with 1uF X7R ceramic capacitors on both input and output, Tj=25°C, and minimum Vin. The latter variables don't matter much according to Fig 2-1.

Comment: I connected to the input and output 1uf electrolite cap and still the current is high , 50ua for mcp1703-3.3 .

Comment: @Ali, can you share a photo of your setup?

Comment: I try to find ceramic capacitor and test again .

Comment: Also, what is the leakage current spec of your capacitor?

Comment: How to send photo ?

Comment: Upload to imgur.com. Share the URL. Someone can edit your question to include the photo in-line.

Comment: Image of my test http://imgur.com/wmHTpDw

Comment: Try a 100 Ohm load and measure only ground current of regulator not load with short leads across 1k * 80uA=80mV. using DMM to probe Vdrop on 1K with short leads to 12V and 0V

Comment: The Op has both input and output caps with <=1uA leakage, what next?

Answer (score -1):

Typical X7R caps are **1 GΩ-uF** or 1 uF = 1 GΩ , 10 uF = 0.1 GΩ  or 100 GΩ max

The MCP1703 specs are given in the table for specific conditions and measured by **the ground current.**

With 12V in and 5V out your load leakage = 80uA

**Your DMM sees a 150 kOhm Req load when the spec is 12V/2uA= 6MΩ**

**Next apply a resistive load of 50mA on output to see if there is any spurious issue with no load. e.g. 5V out/50mA = 100 Ohms**  Expect Regulator ground current to be 30uA.  If your current drops from 80uA to 30uA, then you **may** have a spurious oscillation in your layout of linear regulator.

**So the IC does not appear to meet spec.**

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2frbO0k.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Make sure your assumptions the test set does not induce this leakage with jumper wires from In to out in place of IC.

If that proves valid, then.... Consider (1) ESD damage and discount if careful, then...

Write to Distributor about defective parts and get an RMA. Return Material Authorization or choose better parts.

Comment: image of my test  http://imgur.com/wmHTpDw

Comment: Now see my root cause (2.)  you are using a leaky e-cap.  Measure it alone without regulator.

Comment: I have several of this regulator and each has the same quiescent current. Also I  measured the leakage current of capacitors  in less than 1 ua .

Comment: Then consider if this batch of parts do not meet spec, contact distributor or email OEM,  or measure noise current on a series R of 10k to a scope. or AC measurement using DMM to measure AC and DC voltage drop with short wire jumpers in current loop. to see if it oscillates as The Photon suggested

Comment: Try a 100 Ohm load and measure only ground current of regulator not load with short leads across 1k * 80uA=80mV. using DMM to probe Vdrop on 1K with short leads to 12V

Comment: Mcp1703 image https://500px.com/photo/302419937/dav-by-alikari9999

Comment: Why -1 ?...............

Comment: What do you mean why -1?

Comment: I did not get test with 100 ohm load .

Comment: try this test... I am wonder, who, why, someone downvoted an intelligent reply. Either a troll or a disgruntled user who cannot articulate technical criticism, so a troll.

Comment: I  connected a 100 ohm resistor load and measured the regulator ground current , still it is 50 ua when the load current is 32 ma .
It seems the regulator has problem and I should contact with seller .

Thanks a lot for help